# .net Nano framework on esp32 cam board serial not responding

Tags: nanoframework

I am trying to use .net nano on esp32 cam module. I am able to upload the firmware over serial. After that I can see .net nano boot messages over serial , device explorer also it detects. But no operation on device explorer works eg get device capabilities, erase etc not working.
i am getting ESP32_WROOM_32 @ COM8 is not responding, please reboot the device.
Deployment of new application also fails with the same. Is it because wroom firmware not supported on this cam module ?

this is the firmware log

Connected to ESP32 ESP32D0WDQ6 (revision 1) with MAC address CC50E3B6A7AC
features WiFi, BT, Dual Core, 240MHz, VRef calibration in efuse, Coding Scheme None
Flash information: manufacturer 0x32 device 0x16406 size 4MB
Trying to find ESP32_WROOM_32 in developement repository...OK
Downloading firmware package...OK
Updating to 1.6.1-preview.24
Erasing flash...OK
Flashing firmware...OK

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is no other application "locking" that COM port. Usual suspects are Arduino VS extensions and other utilities that try to find Arduino devices when new COM ports are enumerated.

Comment: when the error happens i can open putty in that port. so its not locked at the time

Comment: What is the output that you get when on a terminal connected to that COM port at 921600?

Comment: this on 921600 https://ibb.co/q9xkStq on 115200 https://ibb.co/g4Tv1WF

Comment: Looks OK. It boots on ESP32 bootloader and it loads the .NET nanoFramework CLR. There is the NFPKT1 showing there. So... it should be picked up by VS.

What is the version of the VS that you have installed? And the version of the nanoFramework extension?

Comment: Vs 2019 and the latest extension from Vs online gallery

Comment: visual stduio version 16.8.4

Comment: All that seems OK. So it has to be with what you're trying to deploy.
Please paste here: 

1) Full output of Device Capabilities

2) Content of packages.config

3) Deployment messages in verbose mode (click the warning icon in the device explorer toolbar)


(for a more interactive help, please join our Discord community [here](https://discord.gg/gCyBu8T) )

Comment: device capabilities , ping etc not working giivng not responding message. I have seen brown out messages sometimes. Iam not sure if the device is getting reset on device explorer actions

Comment: Please go to our Discord community to debug this.